# React Native console.log shows line 35 for all logs

Tags: react-native

Working with:

```
 "react-native": "0.51"
```

When I console.log in Remote JS Debugger, the source of the log is always:

```
console.js:35
```

It ignores the actual line where the log was made from. This used to work as expected. Is there a way to make it work again?

[image: console.log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this was actually caused by having [React Native Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry) installed.

To resolve this whilst in development mode I disabled Sentry, which arguably makes more sense as I only want to be tracking production errors there.

```
// Only run Sentry in production
if (!__DEV__) {
Sentry.config(_CONFIG_URL_HERE_).install();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to disable Sentry, add this to your Sentry init:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: '__YOUR_DSN__',
  integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.Breadcrumbs({
    console: false
  })] 
})
```